# c# webClient Upload String cuts off

Tags: c#, php, string, webclient, uploadstring

I need some help with the C# WebClient UploadString Method. I'm trying to upload a long string (that I read from a database) to a server (PHP) and I'm currently trying to do that with the UploadString Method because it seemed to be the easiest. The problem that I have is that the string that I upload gets cut off after about 4000 characters and I can't figure out why. 
For Example: 
data.length: 19000 (before Upload)
Post.length: 4000 (in PHP)

What I did to bypass this problem: I upload my string in pieces of less than 4000 characters. BUT I still face the problem! Every second upload gets cut off and I can't figure out why. 
This is my C# Code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
        {
            foreach (int y in index)
            {
                data += dr[y] + ";";
                Console.Write(".");
            }
            data += ":";

            if (count1 > 50)
            {
                // Upload the data.
                Console.WriteLine("Uploading Data.....");
                Console.WriteLine("Länge des Strings:" + data.Length);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                client.Dispose();
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string Ergebnis = client.UploadString(address, "POST", data);
                Console.WriteLine(Ergebnis);
                client.Dispose();
                result.ErrorMessage += Ergebnis;
                count1 = -1;
                data = "table="+table+"&columns=continueUpload&values=";

            }
            ++count1;
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea where this comes from? Is there any string limit on the webclient method?

Comment: check ini for post_max_size, upload_max_filesize etc

Comment: I checked that already. Everything is set to 50M and the php cache is up to 500M, so it must be something else.

Comment: Are you urlencoding `data` ?

Comment: not sure what you mean? data is a string that looks like this: `columns=someinformation&values=a quite loooong string`

Comment: `.UploadString` does not apply URLEncoding (`Hello World` => `Hello%20World`) you should `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` the values or use `wc.UploadValues` which does this for you.

Comment: thanks, that did it for me! There was an & in my data string that cut off the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution, thanks Alex for the hint! 
I had to urlencode all my values, than it worked!

Comment: a better explanation would be great