# Maximum data length for WebClient.UploadString method

Tags: c#, query-string, webclient

I have the following code in my asp.net mvc app -

```
string URI = "http://send.url.com/smsapi/sender.php";     
string queryParameters= "a long query string";

string xmlResult = "";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    xmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, queryParameters);
}
```

My question is how long `queryParameters` can be for `WebClient.UploadString` method?

Comment: Have you checked [c# webClient Upload String cuts off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778191/c-sharp-webclient-upload-string-cuts-off)

Comment: If its not documented then its reasonable to assume there isn't one.  Any issue your facing is likely encoding or server side related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebClient` class enforces **no limit** on the length of a string. As far as it is concerned it is transmitting bytes of data.

[Reference Source if you want to check yourself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,d90eef3a57d13003,references)

[And the method it calls](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,e7faeb6132f04f07)

The only theoretical limit is `Int32.MaxValue` bytes because of the internal conversion/encoding methods working with `int`s (~2GB). As long as `Encoding.GetBytes` can handle it and you have sufficient RAM you are unlikely to be limited before that.